# Bitbucket Pipelines - Error running sh script with openjdk:11 and gradle:6.5 containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Spring Boot Kotlin Gradle project, and I'm trying to run a pipeline to build my project using docker-compose to run my CI tests, but I'm not able because docker-compose does not exists

So, following several posts on internet, I created a dependencies.sh file to run before gradle, that will install docker-compose for my tests, but I'm getting the error

`./dependencies.sh: 6: ./dependencies.sh: apk: not found`

I wrote another question about bitbucket pipelines using testcontainers, but so far no one could help me, so I changed the aproach

[Embedded container tests Spring Boot fail on bitbucket pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716456/embedded-container-tests-spring-boot-fail-on-bitbucket-pipeline)

Can someone help me create a bitbucket-pipelines.yml with docker-compose for my tests, so far what I got is:

bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

```
image: openjdk:11

definitions:
  caches:
    gradleall: ~/.gradle
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
  steps:
    - step: &Build
        name: Build and Test
        artifacts:
          - build/libs/**
          - build/reports/**
        script:
          - chmod +x dependencies.sh
          - ./dependencies.sh
          - bash ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace
        services:
          - docker

pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *Build
```

and dependencies.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -eu

# Add python pip and bash
apk add --no-cache py-pip bash

# Install docker-compose via pip
pip install --no-cache-dir docker-compose
docker-compose -v
```

The error is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work

I don't know if it's the best way, but my files ended up like this:

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: amazoncorretto:11-alpine-full

definitions:
  caches:
    gradleall: ~/.gradle
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
  steps:
    - step: &Build
        name: Build and Test
        artifacts:
          - build/libs/**
          - build/reports/**
        script:
          - chmod +x dependencies.sh
          - ./dependencies.sh
          - sh ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace
        services:
          - docker

pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *Build
```

dependencies.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -eu

# Add python pip and bash
apk add --no-cache docker-compose

docker-compose -v
```

Comment: Glad to see you got it! The best I could do from the error was suggest using an Alpine-based image.

Comment: Thx Alex, you gave me the direction

Comment: I was facing a similar problem here. The output of Bitbucket Pipelines was `pipeline.sh not found`. I was using an image: node:alpine. After change to image:node:18.3.0 it works like a charm! Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the main [OpenJDK Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) are based on Debian, which uses `apt-get` instead of `apk`.

You could start by trying `image: openjdk:11-alpine` instead of `image: openjdk:11`; this should allow your current install process to work, but given the following caveat on the Docker page, I am thinking that it may be best to use their Debian images instead of their Alpine ones:

> The OpenJDK port for Alpine is not in a supported release by OpenJDK, since it is not in the mainline code base.

I'm no expert on OpenJDK, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made some progress by changing from openjdk to corretto, but I still couldn't make it work